Change antd accordion text color and collapse content box
How do I change the text color in the ant design accordion to white? I have tried specifically target multiple selectors but can't seems to work. I also want to change the collapsed context box from white to linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(6, 25, 25, 0.328579) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 100%)
Here is the code snippet in codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/rx8z7c
const checklistAccordion = () => {
    const { Panel } = Collapse;

    const accordionData = [
        //...accordion data
    ];

    const renderChildrenAccordion = (children) => {
        return (
            <>
                {children.map((child) => (
                    <Collapse
                        className={s.childrenCollapse}
                        expandIconPosition="end"
                        expandIcon={({ isActive }) => (
                            <img alt="arrow" src="/img/icon/accordion-arrow-down.svg"/>
                        )}
                    >
                        <Panel header={child.label} key={child.key} className={s.childrenPanel}>
                            <p>{child.description}</p>
                        </Panel>
                    </Collapse>
                ))}
            </>
        );
    };

    return (
        <>
            {accordionData.map((item) => (
                <Collapse
                    className={s.parentCollapse}
                    expandIconPosition="end"
                    expandIcon={({ isActive }) => (
                        <img alt="arrow" src="/img/icon/accordion-arrow-down.svg"/>
                    )}
                >
                        <Panel header={item.label} key={item.key} className={s.parentPanel}>
                            <p>{item.description}</p>
                            {renderChildrenAccordion(item.children)}
                        </Panel>
                </Collapse>
            ))}
        </>
    );};


This is something i tried to achieve. It will be a nested accordion that contain different text color. But as for now, I want to change the text header color to white.

Can you please create a codesandbox?

@MuhammadNoumanRafique Here is it https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/rx8z7c .. You can see that the container background when it's collapsed is in white. I want to change this to darker color for both parent and children accordion. Hence, i want to change all the text color to white as well.

Try wrapping Collapse component with ConfigProvider and use tokens to change color like <ConfigProvider theme={{ cssVar: true, components: { Collapse: { colorTextHeading: 'white' } } }}>. Using cssVar: true, you can inspect the content in browser and can see the token used. You can read more here Design Tokens and Global Token. Also as per antd, use items instead of using Panel as Panel is deprecated

Check the antd theme editor playground: https://ant.design/theme-editor.
Then, once your config is defined with your custom colors, you can export it and pass as theme to your ConfigProvider as @MuhammadNoumanRafique suggest
